# if p value is greater than 0.05 for a variable, then why it is considered in multiple regression equation?

Tags: multiple-regression, p-value

Suppose, I have performed multiple regression analysis on the following data set where X1 and X2 are independent variables and Y is the dependent variable.

[image: Data Set]

And achieved the following multiple regression analysis table from where it is clear that X2 is not correlated with Y as the p-value is greater than 0.05 which is 0.108 for X2 variable
[image: Coeffient Table]

So,  if p value is greater than 0.05 for a variable, then why it is considered in regression equation

Y = 2.709 + 0.763(X1) + 0.463(X2) which has been shown in any online multiple regression equation calculator.

My question is Why it is not like the following
Y = 2.709 + 0.763(X1)
omitting the [0.463(X2)] part from the equation, as X2 is not correlated with Y

Please help to clarify the conceptual idea....

Comment: 1) This table that you present in the image is very specialistic. Without further information about how you obtain it (there are multiple ways to calculate these p-values) it is difficult to say anything about it. 2) *Who* is considering the regression equation that you mention? *Where* do you get this from, or *when* does it occur? *What* is this question about? Without this context it is difficult to consider your question about *why?*.

Comment: "it is clear that X2 is not correlated with Y as the p-value is greater than 0.05" is naive from at least two aspects: A) it mixes the concept of descriptive and inductive statistics and B) maybe the other regressor, X1, is confounding the correlation between Y and X1.